# ArcGIS Server 10.5 - Installing and Configuring WebAdaptor (IIS)

Tags: arcgis-server, installation

I have configured ArcGIS WebAdaptor by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxspH3ZV9-g&list=PLZdtVKnSRG07Dw-IJc_UIfK5jgAwdRMh9&index=4) video. Accordingly, the Web Adaptor was successfully added and shown under web adaptors in ArcGIS Server manager as well.
[image]

However, when I try to access with the configured URL `http://gisserver/arcgis`. I get the following message:

> Cannot proxy HTTP request, ArcGIS Server has been configured to accept only HTTPS requests. Please configure your Web Server to use SSL/HTTPS.

Comment: HTTPS has been the rule since 10.1. Have you tried using it?

Answer (score 0):

What is the ArcGIS server setup with HTTP ONLY, HTTP/HTTPS, HTTPS ONLY? I'm guessing HTTPS only.

Depending on what the arcgis server is setup as, the web adaptor has to be installed as such. In your screenshot the web adaptor is HTTP. Before performing the following steps, you'll need a signed SSL certificate for the domain, and the site admin user name and password (setup with server install).

1. You need to import a SSL cert into IIS. (Server Certificates -> Import).
2. You need to update your binding and add a binding for 443 and assign the cert you imported in step 1.
3. Install the web adaptor as 443. This may require uninstalling the web adaptor if you have it installed as 80.
4. After web adaptor install, configure the web adaptor to connect yo your arcgis server. This should automatically load after you install.

Note if you want to use HTTP and not offload a cert in IIS then you'll need to set ArcGIS Server to be HTTP/HTTPS.